# Value type design pattern to replace class

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

We are a looking for a value type design pattern in swift that will allow us to create a shopping cart to hold Products. We are currently using a class but that is a reference type and when we try to add two different version of the same product (i.e. with a different colors or sizes), the first item we added gets changed to the second item we added because it points to the same object in memory.

The design pattern needs to be “global” so we can access it from any page in the app. Right now this is our Cart class that stores all the items in the cart. What do we need to do to make this a value type or how does it need to be reengineered to use a struct without a class?

```
class Cart : NSObject {
    var allProductsInCart = [MainProduct]()

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    class var sharedCart: Cart {
        struct Static {
            static let instance = Cart()

        }
        return Static.instance
    }
}
```

The problem we are getting is that we need the products in the cart to be of custom class “MainProduct.” Right now as you can see, they are stored as “MainProduct.” Do we need to switch the products to a struct or other design pattern as well? How would we do that?

Comment: The question is lacking detail as to why you are seeing the bug. The code you've presented should work fine as long as there are different objects of `MainProduct` being added to the `allProductsInCart` array. Instead of solving this by switching to value types, I would recommend first finding out why two different variations of the same product end up replacing each other. I would argue that a shopping cart does not make sense as a value type. Checkout this [article](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-07-17-when-to-use-swift-structs-and-classes.html) on value vs reference types.

Comment: The issue was solved by switching to a struct for MainProduct. MainProduct was previously a class.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, given the desired behavior between a value type vs. reference type you should use a Struct.

Comment: But how would I do that? Are they implemented the same way as a class? Does even the mainProduct have to be declared as a struct as well? Do we have the same flexibility when using a struct as with a class? How would we covert the let instance = Cart() which makes it accessible from anywhere in the app to apply to a struct?

Comment: @NevinJethmalani Using structs like this without updating the logic will lead to unexpected behaviour. Because you are acting on values not references your global cart won't be updated just by changing to structs.

Answer (score 0):

A commonly used "pattern" for doing this is called "Redux".

The idea is that you have one, immutable version of the "state" of your app.

It can be accessed from anywhere and the only way to update it is through "actions". These will reconstruct the entire state with the required updates.

ViewControllers and views, etc... subscribe to updates of various parts of the state.

So you could have an `AppState` that contains a `ShoppingCartState`. When a product is added to it your `CartViewController` will be informed of this update and can update its view etc...

There are many different frameworks that are built to use Redux so I won't recommend one as you should find the one that is right for you. But I believe this pattern best suits the usage you are after.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot! Our implementation is very simple. Do you have a few that we can look at that you might recommend?

Comment: @NevinJethmalani RESwift is a commonly used framework. We currently use a self-built redux framework. You must ensure to make the state immutable when using Redux. And only to be updated through actions etc... Best of luck with it.